# How can I create a generic method signature for "any map entry" value in the parameter list and/or return type?

Tags: java, generics, methods

In the code that I'm currently refactoring, there exists a similar operation on a bunch of `Maps`. All Maps are of the following type:

```
Map<<SomeType>,Double> myMap;
```

They undergo the same transformation and are converted to:

```
TreeMap<Integer, <SomeType>> transformedMap;
```

I wanted to know if it's possible to create a generic method that looks something like this:

```
public TreeMap<Integer, <T>> transformMap(Map<<T>,Double> myMap){...}
```

What's the way to accomplish this? `SomeType` could be any kind of object/collection. I could replace `<T>` with `Object` but I wanted to know if there is a better solution. The above method signature, obviously doesn't work :)

`SomeTypes` are created by the system and operated upon in the code. I can't make any changes to their source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are close to a generic method solution.  Define your generic type parameter with `<T>`, then use it without its own `<>` in the return type and parameter type.

```
public <T> TreeMap<Integer, T> transformMap(Map<T, Double> myMap) {...}
```

Comment: Ha! I knew I was forgetting something - the generic syntax!